# How to add an element to the front of a vector in C++?

Tags: c++, vector

I only saw push_back which is to add an element to the back of a vector is there a method to add something to the front of the vector? Kind of like push something onto a stack...

Why is it marked duplicate? I literally searched on this website and I couldn't find the answer.

Comment: Pishing onto stack **is** push_back.

Comment: Note that depending your use case, it's possible to insert an element at the front of a `vector`. The answers to the other question all suggest using `deque` instead, but if you only need to insert something at the front once, I don't see the harm in using `vector`.